MAGENTO POS it shows the images on frontend but not in the pos like the picture
MAGENTO POS it shows the images on frontend but not in the pos like the picture.
i had tried, run sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ pub/ var/ even runing all the commands to re-install magento, i dont get any error but this, i can use the pos, i contacted the vendor but no answer yet, and this happened after i installed another pos but i didnt like it and i uninstall it again and after this happed.
